# pip installed under old version of python

Tags: centos6, python, pip

I installed Python 2.6 and pip on centos 6.4. I also upgraded python to 2.7.6 and updated bashrc to reference 2.7.6 for the `python` command.

Pip however, remains under 2.6 and any attempt to reinstall it with 2.7.6 just tells me there's nothing to do as it's already install. How can I install pip under 2.7.6?

I've also tried installing pip with get-pip.py but this is not failing as `zlib is not available` despite having installed zlib.

How can I install pip under 2.7.6?[image]

Comment: Have you tried `yum install python2-pip`?

Comment: This also tells me there's `Nothing to do` yet python27-pip command is still not found

Comment: Sorry, I updated comment.

Comment: Same again unfortunately `Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Show output for `ls -l /usr/bin/pip*`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 281 Aug  3 13:24 /usr/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 283 Aug  3 13:24 /usr/bin/pip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 287 Aug  3 13:24 /usr/bin/pip2.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63269/discussion-between-alexander-tolkachev-and-fraser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have strange problem. As we discussed in chat try to install pip by `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python2.7 -`.

Then create file `/usr/bin/pip2.7` and fill it with:

```
#!/bin/python2.7

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Make it executable `chmod +x /usr/bin/pip2.7` and run it.